# GPS stopped working after update

Tags: gps

I recently [asked a question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/usb-transfer-speed-ridiculously-slow) on this site about how to stop my USB transfers from being so slow on my rooted Galaxy S2. It was suggested to me that I update my kernel and/or ROM. That seemed reasonable, so I did. I now have the [latest kernel](http://www.gokhanmoral.com/gm/2012/07/29/siyahkernel-s2-v3-5/) version and [latest ROM](http://get.cm/?device=galaxys2).

And now, after doing so, my GPS is completely unresponsive.

So now I'm playing feature-whack-a-mole again. Something I was doing a while back when I could either have my compass or my WiFi, but not both.

How do I get out of this? How do I get my GPS back and not be juggling every other feature on my phone?

(... and I'm not even sure my USB problems are solved...)

Comment: Sorry to see you struggling with issues. Have you seen the app called "GPS Aids" in Google Play Store? I stumbled on this app once and I believe this is the one for Samsung phones which has GPS related issues. Have try, with a pinch of salt ;-)

Comment: I also stumbled on an app in play store, that explains the issue. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fatdroid.android.gpscontrols2ad&hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GPS was fixed by downloading [a "tweak" script](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43064965/XDA/Galaxy%20S2/sc-02c_tweaker_siyah352ntt.zip), whatever that is, from here. I originally found it on [this thread on XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1126190&page=169).